# javafx load generic controller from fxml

Tags: java, generics, javafx-8

I want to achieve generic code for loading fxml and set data for that fxml. Following is my function to load child fxml. Now i want to figure out how i can get controller name from getLoader and do not need to hard-code OwnerViewController. So i can set data for each fxml pass to the function argument. My controller have OwnerViewController setData method and its working fine. I just want to make my controller name to dyanamic.

```
public void loadAnchorPaneWithData(AnchorPane ap, String a, Object data) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/herudi/view/"+a));
        AnchorPane p = loader.load();

        OwnerViewController controller = loader.getController();

        controller.setData(data);

        ap.getChildren().setAll(p);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass parameter as an object and check that object is instance which controller from your `loadAnchorPaneWithData` method

Comment: well any other better way like create a base controller and extend it in all my other controller ? if i check instance of the object then i have to write if else code and every time i added new fxml i need to rewrite this code as well